# How to provide a Community User access to delete a Contact in SalesForce Community?

Tags: community

The Community User is not having permission to delete a Contact. Is there a workaround to achieve this?

In fact I want to enable a Community User to merge his Contact with another Contact (in case of duplicate Contacts). But as this user is not having permission to delete a Contact, he is unable to merge with another Contact.

I had tried to merge the Contacts through trigger but for Community User the trigger fails with an exception saying Insufficient Access Read Only.

Kindly help me to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I wont go into whether providing this functionality to end users is a good idea or not, but you'd likely succeed by creating a domain layer services class, and then add a service/method to it to which your user would be able to pass record ids etc that they do have read access to. The method would then run in system context, not user context, and so be able to complete the task.

Comment: Can you please provide any  working example or reference link for this?

Comment: Hi there sorry no I dont have any code relevant to this topic. Please review the following article for further discussion on the approach https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns